# SQL Query - join on less than or equal date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join

I'm having trouble figuring out how to format the following query. I want to take `Table A` and left join `Table B`. Not only on `a.country = b.country` but also on the `max start_date` that is less than equal to `join_date`.

**Postgres (Redshift)**

**Table A**

```
  ID      join_date     country          email     
 -----    -----------   ---------        ------
  124     '2013-10-03'     US         john@doe.com
  423     '2013-04-21'     CA         bob@doe.com
  412     '2013-03-30'     US         test@test.com
```

**Table B**

```
  start_date        country          joined_from
-------------     -----------       --------------
'2013-08-21'          US                google
'2014-01-02'          CA                yahoo
'2013-03-02'          CA                microsoft
'2013-02-10'          US                facebook
'2013-09-01'          US                yahoo
```

**End Result**

```
  ID     join_date     country      email         start_date     joined_from
------  -----------    ---------   ---------     ------------   -------------
 124    '2013-10-03'     US        john@doe.com   '2013-09-01'     yahoo
 423    '2013-04-21'     CA        bob@doe.com    '2013-03-02'    microsoft
 412    '2013-03-30'     US        test@test.com  '2013-02-10'    facebook
```

Comment: What have you tried? `SELECT * from A a LEFT JOIN B b on a.country = b.country WHERE b.start_date <= a.join_date` does not work?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda I don't think so, since he wants the row with the maximum date that is less than the join_date, not every row from that table

Comment: Lamak is correct, thanks though

Answer (score 9):

Not pretty, but putting your condition directly in the `JOIN` should work:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.join_date, a.country, a.email, b.start_date, b.joined_from
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.country = b.country 
      AND b.start_date = (
          SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM b b2 
          WHERE b2.country = a.country AND b2.start_date <= a.join_date
      );
```

Comment: Great! Works in my case as well