# MySQL Filtering Data from one table using value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have `tblCustomers` with a field `DateOfRegistration`.

I have a second tbl that contains data that I want each customer to be able to view. One of the fields contains a `ReferenceDate`. 
However, when customer "A" reads the information from the second table I want to restrict the information they view based on the `ReferenceDate` to be equal to or greater than their `DateOfRegistration`

Comment: is that MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And it would better if you add some sample data with current output and expected output

Comment: I haven't attempted any solution yet.

Comment: Customers will be registering day by day. The information in the other table is added to day by day. What I want is that for any given customer they can only see the data that was entered on or after the date they regurgitated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) . If you can provide some sample data I can give you a more detailed explanaition.

Comment: Ok it will take me some time as I can't use the data I have as its subject to NDA. I will post table structure in due course.

Comment: I am familiar with Join but I need one end of it so to speak to specify => than and not just equal to.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413590/sql-query-join-on-less-than-or-equal-date)